# automatically append images in a table with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, merge, append

I know [this solution to append images in rows and columns](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append_array).

By the way I would like to arrange the images in a square table automatically regardless of their number and without grouping them with the parenthesis.

Example output:
[image]

Is it possible to do that with [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)?

---

```
convert \( Img1.jpg Img2.jpg +append \) \
          \( Img3.jpg Img4.jpg +append \) \
          -background none -append   append_array.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Montage` from imagemagick.

You can easily use `montage`<sup>[[1](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#concatenate)]</sup> that you should have installed with imagemagick.

From the current directory you can run for example:

```
montage -resize 400x *  -mode Concatenate -tile 2x  AnotherDir/montage_array.jpg
```

[image: Pircure regenerated]

**Notes**:

- You have to save in another directory (or select from another directory) else you could find an empty slot in place of the image that you are creating.
- `-resize 400x` to scale each source image to the same dimension
- `-tile 2x` to have 2 columns , `-tile x2` for two rows...
- ```
           #   +--------+---------+   Sequence of images
           #   +    1   +    2    +    for the code used
           #   +--------+---------+     in the above example
           #   +    3   +    4    +
           #   +--------+---------+   I cut the image from
           #   +    5   +    6... +     the one you post...
           #   +--------+---------+
  ```
- but you can do much much more...

  [image]